# Does the enthalpy of formation include translational and rotational energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I can look up the enthalpy of formation of water vapor and get -241,826 KJ/mol. I want to use this to compute the total energy of water vapor at STP from the energies of O2 and H2 gas. What I don't know is whether I should use the electronic energies of H2 gas and O2 gas or the total energies of H2 gas and O2 gas, which include the contributions from the translational and rotational partition functions.

Basically, which of these two is the correct usage of Enthalpy of Formation?

1. E<sub>Total</sub>(H2O) = E<sub>electronic</sub>(O2) + E<sub>electronic</sub>(H2) -241,826 KJ/mol + E<sub>Translational</sub>(H2O) + E<sub>Rotational</sub>(H2O)
2. E<sub>Total</sub>(H2O) = E<sub>Total</sub>(O2) + E<sub>Total</sub>(H2) -241,826 KJ/mol

Comment: What about vibrational energy and zero point energy correction?
Thermal corrections include all degrees of freedom that are excited at the specified temperature. No idea why you get the idea to dump some degrees of freedom in the first place...

Comment: Btw. Gaussian has a full reference for how thermal corrections are done: https://gaussian.com/thermo/

Comment: What about translation and rotation of H2 and O2 ?

Comment: @Kexanone at room temperature, the vibrational modes are all frozen out. We can ignore them comfortably in the scenario I proposed due to the exponential dependence of the partition function on the eigenstate energy, but you are correct for sufficiently hot gases they are relevant. Most textbooks cover this "dumping" of certain degrees of freedom under the section on "Equipartition of energy"

Comment: @Poutnik I am using total energy to refer to the translation and rotation added to the electronic (DFT) energy. So when I say the total energy of O2 or H2 above, that is what I am referring to.

Comment: @colinb I mean, it is rather inconsistent to explicitly involve them in the equation for H2O, but not for O2 and H2. Regarding vibration energy, it would be quite complicated to involve different degree of influence of quantum vibration quantisation for all involved vibration modes.

Comment: @ColinB Yes, you can dump degrees of freedom, if the temperature is too low to excite it. Maybe your textbook dumps it, but actual computational software like Gaussian doesn't. It's up to you how accurate you want to be. Btw. under ideal gas conditions $H = E_{total} + RT$.

Comment: @Kexanone ah perfect, that's the relationship I was looking for! Yes already the rotational only contributes about 4 millihartree for this system, and DFT is at absolute best accurate to 1 millihartree, and since the vibrational is going to be at least an order of magnitude less, it's not gonna matter.

Answer (score -1):

To add to @Kexanone's answer above, the enthalpy of formation refers to how much heat is evolved or adsorbed from the environment in a reaction. So it's the total energy, and in an ideal gas it has the form: dft + translational + rotational + vibrational + PdV, where the PdV refers to the energy needed to make space for the gas (grand canonical ensemble; in the canonical ensemble (fixed volume) this does not show up). At room temperature the vibrational and PdV terms are typically small compared to DFT energy errors (order 1 millihartree), with the PdV term only coming into play at pressures within an order of magnitude or two of those found in the detonation of thermonuclear bombs.

Comment: Nope, there is no work. SCF energy + thermal corrections for all relevant degrees of freedom is all there is for the internal energy. Again, I strongly advice to use https://gaussian.com/thermo/ as a reference.

Comment: 1) At T = 298 K, and p = 1 atm, the $p \Delta V$ term for the formation of $\ce{H2O(g)}$ is –12.3 L atm/mol = –1.3 kJ/mol.  That's comparable  to 1 millihartree (=> 2.6 kJ/mol).  At 10 atm, the   $p \Delta V$ term becomes 13 kJ/mol, significantly exceeding your stated DFT energy error. Saying this term only becomes significant at pressures within an order of magnitude of those in a thermonuclear explosion is silly.
2) Ideal gases have no internal structure, and thus no vibrational energy.

Comment: 2) Is fine. We are working here with a hybrid model. We still neglect the eigenvolume and interaction between the particles, but allow an internal structure, and thus a more complex heat capacity.

Comment: @Kexanone I don't do DFT, so maybe there is some looseness of the term there but, substantively, it seems incorrect to refer to such a hybrid as an ideal gas (one of whose essential characteristics is a lack of vibrational DOF's) rather than as, say, an ideal gas hybrid.

Comment: I'm not sure either. It still follow the ideal gas law $pV=nRT$ though.